# Adding subcommand within Sublimetext custom build

Tags: build, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-build

In Sublimetext editor, we can specify [custom build command](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html) using `shell_cmd` exec Target Options.

I want to add a subcommand within `shell_cmd` value. For Linux terminal commands, this can be done as `outer-bin arg1 $(inner-command)`, where `$(inner-command)` provides the second argument for the `outer-bin` command.

I edit and run [Tamarin](https://tamarin-prover.github.io/) models with Sublimetext. Some model files (e.g. [LAK06-UK3.spthy](https://github.com/tamarin-prover/tamarin-prover/blob/develop/examples/features/xor/diff-models/LAK06-UK3.spthy)) contain user-defined lemma (e.g. `executable`) and some implicit lemmas (e.g.  `Observational_equivalence`). The default Tamarin command with `--prove` flag proves all user-defined and implicit lemmas. However, with the subcommand in the build system, I wish to pass only user-defined lemma. The build command including the subcommand for the [LAK06-UK3.spthy](https://github.com/tamarin-prover/tamarin-prover/blob/develop/examples/features/xor/diff-models/LAK06-UK3.spthy) could be:

`tamarin-prover --diff LAK06-UK3.spthy $(python3 extract_lemma_cmd.py LAK06-UK3.spthy)`

which translates to

`tamarin-prover --diff LAK06-UK3.spthy --prove=executable`

Any idea, how can I do this for Sublimetext custom build command?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: added the case example

Comment: The contents of `shell_cmd` is passed directly to the shell to eecute, so your example of `outer-bin args $(inner-command)` should work just fine; does it not? Something to note is that `$` is special in build systems, so you need to enter it as `\\$` so that Sublime passes it to the shell as `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$()` for command substitution, you just need to escape the `$`:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "tamarin-prover --diff $file_name \\$(python3 extract_lemma_cmd.py $file_name)",
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

Make sure you use a double backslash `\\$` for the escape.

Another solution is to use backticks:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "tamarin-prover --diff $file_name `python3 extract_lemma_cmd.py $file_name`",
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

Please note that these `shell_cmd`s will only work as-is on Linux and Mac. For Windows, they need to be run using `bash -c`, as the default shell on Windows is `cmd.exe`.